# If I’m offered a job, can I postpone the start date due to Covid19 concerns?

Tags: job-offer

I applied for a job a of couple months ago for PRN work and just had an interview this week. I felt the interview went well. If I get offered a job can I ask them to delay my start date a couple weeks due to Covid19 concerns? I am currently on an 8 week furlough from my other employer. I am a Physical Therapist Assistant.

Comment: Why are you asking us? You should be asking them this question.

Comment: *PRN work*? Please [edit] your question to explain that term.

Comment: You can ask them whatever you want to ask. Are you asking us whether you can _insist on/ensure_ postponing the date?

Comment: Hi Debbie. I voted to close your question because currently it is answered by a simple "Yes" which does not provide much value either to you nor to future readers. Maybe you can edit your Question to make it fit better. Tell us what you are having trouble with. Is it the how-to communicate your concerns? What do you want to achieve? Coivd-situation could go on for a while, do you want to postpone indefinitely?

Answer (score 1):

You can ask, it doesn't hurt to ask. But prepare for the answer.

Either it will be Yes and they will put it on hold for the time being and wait for you. But there are risks with this like they may put the job on hold completely, they might find someone willing to move etc. But given the current climate people are nervous to commit to moving roles - they should understand that. Hopefully they have thought of this.

Or

No, because they need someone one now. And you could risk on loosing out on the opportunity.

You're also on furlough as you're company I assume are trying to ride out the storm, they may also be doing the same.

Chances are this being a couple of months ago you might not actually hear anything anyway due to the rapid rise of Covid-19

Answer (score 1):

You can ask. I’d think very hard about what to do and what exactly to ask. And it depends very much on which country you are in.

Apparently your current employer doesn’t want you to work and doesn’t want to pay you. Your new employer will likely be in the exact same situation, so there may be no need to ask them. They will bring up the question themselves.

You should have told us your location. Your English seems fine, so I guess New Zealand or Irish Republic (that’s why you should give your location, so we don’t have to guess). Check what your government does right now to help people and decide what’s best for you financially.

Comment: Why New Zealand or Ireland?

Comment: @guest, UK or Canada (not US because of the word furlough) (not Ireland and not Zealand because of the job title PRN).